# Symfony 4 dependecy injection - Define constructor arguments depending on use case

Tags: php, symfony, dependency-injection, symfony4

I have a generic service who uses a configuration to do its processing.

```php
<?php

namespace App\Service;

class MyCustomService
{
    /**
     * @var array
     */
    private $config;

    /**
     * MyCustomService constructor.
     *
     * @param array $config
     */
    public function __construct(array $config)
    {
        $this->config = $config;
    }

    public function getConfig()
    {
        return $this->config;
    }
}
```

I want to inject that service in my controller's actions. But with a specific configuration for each action.

```php
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use App\Service\MyCustomService;

class MyCustomController
{
    public function action_1(MyCustomService $myCustomService)
    {
        /**
         * $config must contain 
         * ['foo' => 'bar']
         */
        $config = $myCustomService->getConfig();
    }

    public function action_2(MyCustomService $myCustomService)
    {
        /**
         * $config must contain
         * ['foo' => 'baz']
         */
        $config = $myCustomService->getConfig();
    }
}
```

How can I do that using `config/services. Yaml`?

Is there a way to configure a controller action?

Like this, for example:

```yaml
services: 
    #...
    #...
    #...
        
    App\Controller\MyCustomController:action_1:
        arguments:
            $myCustomService: 
                App\Service\MyCustomService:
                    arguments:
                        $config: {foo: 'bar'}
        
    App\Controller\MyCustomController:action_2:
        arguments:
            $myCustomService: 
                App\Service\MyCustomService:
                    arguments:
                        $config: {foo: 'baz'}
```

I could use a config method inside MyCustomService, and call it inside every controller's action. But it's not that elegant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define different instances (eg.: with different configurations) by doing something like

```
services:
 App\Service\MyCustomService $s1:
  config: 
    - foo: 'bar'
```

And inject in controller action like

```
public function action_1(MyCustomService $s1)
```

Arguments are matched by name and everytime you define an argument with that signature (class name + argument name) Symfony will inject the right instance.

You should also set `autowire` and [register controllers as services](https://symfony.com/doc/4.3/service_container/3.3-di-changes.html#controllers-are-registered-as-services)